# Does my the module list on my node update when I add a php module in a chef recipe?

Tags: php, chef-infra

I am putting together a custom nginx web server cookbook working with php for a project of mine. Along with both of those, I have several php modules that I need installed as well.

I have a dependency written for the php and memcached cookbook.

```
depends 'php', '~> 1.7.2'   
depends 'memcached', '~> 2.0.2'
```

I have a `php_pear` resource written to install the memcached module.

```
php_pear 'memcached' do
   action :install
end
```

When I update the node, everything runs to completion and it says it updated resources.

The issue is when I ssh on the server and run `php -m|grep memcached` to confirm the module is installed. It is not listed there.

My question is:

Is the memcached module installed and just not being listed or am I missing something in my chef recipe to actually enable that module?

Comment: That should be enough to have the module installed and activated. What platform are you using? Any clues in the chef run logs?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and the chef run logs don't reveal much. I am trying to set up some code to test that the module is working, but I am not sure how.

Comment: The module must appear in the `php -m` output. You can also use `php -i` to check that the module is loaded.